# Is there some way to prevent Windows 10 from updating the opened list of processes for a "task group" while the mouse cursor is over it?

Tags: windows-10, taskbar

I constantly have 10 or more cmd.exe windows opened at any given time, sometimes many more. These are all launched minimized, by my scripts, so they are never noticed by me in any way. They group themselves into the cmd.exe icon in the Task bar.

When I click with the left mouse button on this "task group", it opens up the list of tasks. I then try to click a specific one in the list, but my scripts launch more ones at that moment, resulting in me clicking the wrong one. This happens many times a day for me and is very annoying.

Is there some sort of setting where I can make it so that this "list" is not updated while opened, much like the Firefox and Pale Moon web browsers don't instantly update the tabs until you move away the cursor from the tab area, in order to not confuse the user?

If this can be set somehow, that would be lovely.

Comment: Generally one does not need to click on an icon in the Taskbar. Just hover over it and do not click on it and it will show you what is going on.